# How do I find Mod value of a position and b position with perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

Now I had the data (txt file). How do I find the Mod value of the a position and b position.
For example:

```
 my data:
  posi 
    13628   16195   GTG GAA BL4_0018
    14185   14185   T   C
    20000   16543   ATG GAC BL4_0019
Hope The result : 
  posi
  Mod value 16195   GTG GAA BL4_0018
  Mod value 14185   T   C
  Mod value 16543   ATG GAC BL4_0019
Mod value=(present-current)%3+1
```

I hope the result were printed with all of colums.I would appreciate if you could give some pointers.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?

Comment: I want to insert the txt file and find the mod value at the position colums.Just only the value of the positions were changed But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my ($current, $previous, $rest, $prest);
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^\s*(\d+)(.*)$/) {
        $current = $1;
        $rest = $2;
    }
    if (defined $previous) {
        my $mod = ($current - $previous) % 3 + 1;
        print  "$mod $rest\n";
    }
    $previous = $current;
}

__DATA__
 posi 
    13628   16195   GTG GAA BL4_0018
    14185   14185   T   C
    20000   16543   ATG GAC BL4_0019
```

**output:**

```
3    14185   T   C
2    16543   ATG GAC BL4_0019
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very good. But I hope the results were printed as list beacause it is not only the position colum but also a lot of colums. Could you show me how to do that.

Comment: @Phan: I don't well understand what you need :-( But you can just do a `print` instead of a `push` to see the results.

Comment: @ M45: could you see my question one again. I had write it again.

Comment: @M45:sorry M45 I don't write the good question. It is realy I hope to do that. But at the posision could you show me to make the value mod . I mean it Same the first your answer 1.2 or 3.

by the way.could please you show me one again the code of first answer. thank you so much.

Comment: @Phan: You can see the previous versions of an answer by clicking on the `edited N mins ago` link

Comment: @Phan: my pseudo is M42 not M45 :-) I've edited my answer to give new the value of the modulo.

Comment: @M42: Thank you very much.How could I insert the mod value at the current row. I mean with the mod value ( EX:(14185 -13618)%3+1 = 3 ) was printed in the current row (EX: 14185, T, C)

Comment: @M42: How about that if I replace print  "$mod $prest\n"; with print  "$mod $rest\n"